# Is there any way to consolidate these multiple lines of code?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

[Here is an example of what my code does.](http://jsfiddle.net/mvNCz/3/)

I am trying to develop a website that has many iterations of the following code:

```
$(function() {
    $('.nav1, .nav1x').not('#current').hover(
        function () {
            $(".nav1x a").css("visibility","visible");
          },
          function () {
            $(".nav1x a").css("visibility","hidden");
          }
    );
    $(".nav2, .nav2x").not('#current').hover(
        function () {
            $(".nav2x a").css("visibility","visible");
          },
          function () {
            $(".nav2x a").css("visibility","hidden");
          }
    );
    $(".nav3, .nav3x").not('#current').hover(
        function () {
            $(".nav3x a").css("visibility","visible");
          },
          function () {
            $(".nav3x a").css("visibility","hidden");
          }
    );
    $(".nav4, .nav4x").not('#current').hover(
        function () {
            $(".nav4x a").css("visibility","visible");
          },
          function () {
            $(".nav4x a").css("visibility","hidden");
          }
      );
});
```

Due to the nature of the selection I do not know how to write this more simply. It has a hover event on both the .nav1 and .nav1x to prevent a flickering which otherwise occurs on my website so this has to remain. Do any of you clever people know a better way to write this?

Comment: Probably a better fit for http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Oh I haven't seen this exchange before. Is there a way to transfer it there?

Comment: Would it be possible to add a `nav` class that those `nav1`, `nav2`... have in common?

Comment: If all you are doing is hiding and showing, why aren't you doing this in CSS directly?

Comment: See my answer, fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gibble/mvNCz/5

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems to work: http://jsfiddle.net/gibble/mvNCz/5/

```
$(function() {
    $.each(['nav1', 'nav2', 'nav3', 'nav4'], function(index, value) {
        $("." + value + ", ." + value + "x").not('#current').hover(
            function () {
                $("." + value + "x a").css("visibility","visible");
            },
            function () {
                $("." + value  + "x a").css("visibility","hidden");
            }
        );
    });
});
```

Comment: Yikes, looks like a maintenance nightmare to me! Not your fault though, the code wasn't structured right to begin with.

Comment: @aziz.punjani, agreed.  Normally I'd use string.format instead of concatenation, but the issue is the html isn't ideal.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest restructuring your code, the current structure of the html is redundant. [Here's my approach](http://jsfiddle.net/mvNCz/6/) at simplifying the menu.

The HTML

```
  <ul class="nav">
        <li id="current"><a href="#">Images</a></li>
        <li><span>.</span></li>
        <li><a href="#">Articles</a></li>
        <li><span>.</span></li>
        <li><a href="#">Links</a></li>
        <li><span>.</span></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
```

The CSS

```
.nav li{ display: inline;}
.nav li span, .nav li a{   
    font-size: 24px; 
    text-decoration:  none;
    color:black; 
}

.clone li a { color: blue }​
```

The javascript

```
$('.nav').clone().addClass('clone').insertAfter('.nav').find('li').css('visibility', 'hidden');

$('.nav').on('hover', 'li', function(e){ 
    if( e.type === 'mouseenter' )
        $('.clone').find('li').eq( $(this).index() ).css('visibility', 'visible'); 
    else if( e.type === 'mouseleave' )
        $('.clone').find('li').eq( $(this).index() ).css('visibility', 'hidden');  
});
```

The problem with your current code is that for any future menu items you will have to make changes to three different places twice in the html and once in the javascript. With the code above you just make a change once to the html.

Answer (score 2):

you can do it without javascript at all: http://jsfiddle.net/Shmiddty/mvNCz/7/

```
.nav li{ display: inline;position:relative;}
.nav li span, .nav li a{   
    font-size: 24px; 
    text-decoration:  none;
    color:black; 
}

.nav li + li:before{
    content:'.';
    font-size:24px;
    display:inline-block;
    padding:0 .25em;
}

.nav li.current:after,
.nav li:hover:after{
    content:attr(data-name);
    font-size:24px;
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    top:1em;
    color:#00f;
}
.nav li+li.current:after,
.nav li+li:hover:after{
    left:.75em;
}
```

HTML

```
<ul class="nav">
    <li class="current" data-name="Images"><a href="#">Images</a></li>
    <li data-name="Articles"><a href="#">Articles</a></li>
    <li data-name="Links"><a href="#">Links</a></li>
    <li data-name="Contact"><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: pretty cool [browser support](http://www.browsersupport.net/CSS/content%3Aattr()) also

Comment: Interesting approach. I like it +1. Just one question though, the last part in the css couldn't you just do `.nav li+li:hover:after{ left:.75em; }` Why the repeated code for the other properties ?

Comment: @GionaF That is honestly better than I was expecting. :)

Comment: @aziz.punjani I tried that and it seems that it overrides the previous definition of after completely. (in chrome, at least)

Comment: A "reflection" effect: http://jsfiddle.net/Shmiddty/mvNCz/10/

Comment: Yeah this is what I've done basically, but with a highlight sort of effect. This is very useful stuff guys, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

For your knowledge, a more JQuery way to write the same code would be:

```
$(".nav li[id!=current]").hover(
    function () {
        $("."+ $(this).attr("class") + "x a").css("visibility","visible");
    }, 
      function () {
        $("."+ $(this).attr("class") + "x a").css("visibility","hidden");
    }
);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/96wvB/